# Terminal error no available formula with the name start

Tags: mysql, terminal, homebrew

I am trying to get my mysql server running... but I keep getting this error when I try to start the server. How do I solve this?

**Input in terminal**

`brew services mysql start`

**Error message**

> No available formula with the name "start". Did you mean star, kstart or qstat?

Answer (score 1):

It should be `brew services start mysql`

And you can use `brew services list` to check if it has been actually started.

```
$ brew services list
Name           Status  User File
docker-machine none
mysql          started rui  ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```